# Can i use daringFireball Markdown within my JAVA application

Tags: java, markdown

Here's the link of [daringfireball Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). Can i use this API in my java project? I read the whole site and did not find anything that could help me figure it out.

I also went to the wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to see if there was more API that do the same thing, but they're for web language like PHP or ruby.

I want my user to be able to use markdown as it is more simple for a non-programmer to type with this syntax.

If not, is there any other API that does the same thing for JAVA? Would it be hard to implement such thing my self as i am a starter experienced programmeer?

Thanks

Comment: daringfireball's implementation is in Perl, so I don't see how you could use it in Java. See https://github.com/jgm/CommonMark/wiki/List-of-CommonMark-Implementations for a list of implementations of CommonMark, which is stricter Markdown specification.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, i'll have a look.

Comment: @JBNizet after looking at the code, i found that there is some missing code within the API. It's missing a package named `IInline`. Any idea?

Comment: @JBNizet I just found out this : https://code.google.com/p/markdown4j/ . It look pretty good. Now i have to try it and see if it is easy to use. Bonne soirée.